# How to pass value to select option

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

i want to pass the value from one page to another's option

value of array want to pass when click accSummary (direct to the desired page)which will invoke a function :

```
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = '<a href="acc.html" onclick="getSum[0]">'+accSummary[0].accNo +'</a>';
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = '<a href="acc.html" onclick="getSum[2]">'+accSummary[0].accNo +'</a>';

function invoked: (i try to store the value in localStorage)

getSum(no){
     localStorage.setItem("accNo",accDetail[no]);
}
```

i write this script to get the value

```
<script>window.onload = function () { 
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
      localStorage.accDetail[no];var createTrans=getTransactions();
</script>
```

however, it turns out that the no (localStorage.accDetail[no])is undefined.

what's the problem

Comment: why there is square bracket in **onclick='getSum(0)'**

Comment: define as a  function `function getSum(no)`

Answer (score 1):

**Try like this**

1.function not define `function getSum(no)`.

2.change the `getSum(0)` instead of `getSum[0]`.

3.Already you have declare the local storage value.So retrieve the data like this **[localStorage.getItem("accNo");](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local)**

```
 document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = '<a href="acc.html" onclick="getSum(0)">'+accSummary[0].accNo +'</a>';
 document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = '<a href="acc.html" onclick="getSum(2)">'+accSummary[0].accNo +'</a>';



   function getSum(no){ //its a function
         localStorage.setItem("accNo",accDetail[no]); //assign the value to local
    }

        <script>
             window.onload = function () { 
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =localStorage.getItem("accNo"); //retrieve the data like this
              var createTrans=getTransactions();
        </script>
```